# Restore mongo with authentication

Tags: mongodb

This is my user:

```
> db.getUser("root")
{
    "_id" : "admin.root",
    "user" : "root",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "dbOwner",
            "db" : "arasaac"
        },
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to restore arasaac db.

However:

```
root@mongodb:/# mongorestore --archive="./arasaac31102019.archive" --db arasaac  --username root --password ***** --drop --authenticationDatabase admin

2019-10-31T09:59:26.797+0000    Failed: error connecting to db server: server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed.
```

I thought root role was enough. I also added `dbOwner` role to the database I want to restore, but no luck.

Comment: are you  trying with localhost and does it has auth?

Comment: localhost and auth is working as I enter mongo prompt authenticating.

Comment: have you used any special characters in password?

Comment: No, just letters and numbers